# Reference citation from en dash to hyphen

Tags: cite-package

I am currently using a `cite` package. In order to make the reference citation into [1-3] but I want to change the en dash to hyphen.

Here is my sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{Sample File}
\date{}
\maketitle
\cite{CR1,CR2,CR3} - current output

[1-3] - required output
%I want my output to be hyphen not en dash

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\bibitem{CR1}
Author 1, title, journaltitle , year

\bibitem{CR2}
Author 2, title, journaltitle, year

\bibitem{CR3}
Author 3, title, journaltitle, year

\bibitem{CR4}
Author 4, title, journaltitle, year

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know that a hyphen is wrong here, I assume?

Comment: @JosephWright So, no other way to change that one?

Comment: It certainly can be changed, I was just pointing out that typographic tradition, at least in English, uses an en-dash for ranges of numbers and a hyphen only for hyphenating words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can alter the output here using `\citedash`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
% \show\citedash % => \hbox {--}\penalty \citepunctpenalty
\renewcommand*{\citedash}{\hbox{-}\penalty\citepunctpenalty}
\begin{document}

\title{Sample File}
\date{}
\maketitle
\cite{CR1,CR2,CR3} - current output

[1-3] - required output
%I want my output to be hyphen not en dash

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\bibitem{CR1}
Author 1, title, journaltitle , year

\bibitem{CR2}
Author 2, title, journaltitle, year

\bibitem{CR3}
Author 3, title, journaltitle, year

\bibitem{CR4}
Author 4, title, journaltitle, year

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here, I've kept the penalty that `cite` includes by default so that breaking at the hyphen is still discouraged.